# Disk tool points out that the partition is misaligned by 512 Bytes

Tags: partitioning

the disk tool points out that the partition is misaligned by 512 Bytes.
The Ubuntu system is my secondary to win xp sp3,and the partition mentioned is the ubuntu`s partition with ntfs file sys.
Questions:1.Should I fix it? if y how? 2.Can it mess some win handling of this particular partition if changed by linux?
Thanks

Comment: Your Ubuntu partition with NTFS?, did you installed Ubuntu on a NTFS partition? or is it a shared NTFS partition for Ubuntu and XP?.

Comment: One of the questions here should help you: [partition misaligned](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=partition+misaligned&submit=search)

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on NTFS a logical partition

Answer (score 0):

Show the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print` (or change `/dev/sda` to whatever's relevant). Also, what model disk do you have? If it's an older one (made in 2009 or earlier, before Advanced Format became common), it's not an issue; but if it's a newer disk, partition alignment to 8-sector boundaries is important. Chances are you're seeing a bug that causes the program to overreact to certain conditions, but there could be a real problem.